# How to enable and disable qDebug() messages

Tags: qt, qdebug

I disable the qDebug() messages by writing

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release):DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
```

in the .pro file. This works fine. I would like to know if there is any way to enable qDebug() messages using the source code. I would like to send it as an argument to the application. Therefore by default I will have the qDebug() messages disabled, but with an argument stating to switch on the qDebug() messages I need the qDebug() enabled. Is it possible to do this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can look at `qInstallMsgHandler` documentation.

Comment: @vahancho that line in .pro file not stop console.log for me

Comment: @mohammadalabid, why do you add it to .pro file? It should be added to your sorce code. Please see the answer on this question and Qt docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler .

Comment: i mean this line
CONFIG(release, debug|release):DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add your own function for handling Qt debug messages with [qInstallMsgHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler)

This will allow you to control whether to print the messages.

Answer (score 17):

You can control QDebug (and all messages) at runtime via a few options:

1. [QLoggingCategory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html) Which allows you to use environment variables or config files.  For example with Qt 5.6 you can do: `QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=false;driver.usb.debug=true"` turns on qDebug for everything except USB debug.  If you need a more complicated setup, or if you are using Qt 5.5 or earlier you can turn on and off individual debug messages via a qtlogging.ini file.
2. [QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html#warning-and-debugging-messages) can also be used to control message output as well as doing [formatting](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qSetMessagePattern).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code to my qmake project file enabled qDebug() messages for release builds on Windows/MSYS, even without the qInstallMsgHandler():

```
CONFIG += console
CONFIG += warn_on
```